# Changing SSAS mode from tabular to multidimensional

Tags: ssas, ssms, ssas-tabular

When i've tried to deploy a cube using SSAS in Visual Studio, i've came across a error which said that the localhost is not being executed in a multidimensional mode.

After further investigation on SSMS, it is clear that SSAS is clearly running on a Tabular mode.

[image]

My question is: It is possible to revert the localhost mode and change it from Tabular to Multidimensional?

Any help is really apreciated.

Anna

Comment: It's not officially supported, but see a hack here: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Analysis+Services+(SSAS)/147503/
(should work either way)

Comment: When writing a question you may (or may not) have seen that a [list of relevant/similar questions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z48sn.png) appear while you're typing the question's title. Next time take a look at them to try to find the answer you are looking for before asking a new question.